# Multilist with search not loading for non admin

Tags: content-search, content-editor, sitecore-query

Data on the left side of the multi-list is not loading if the user is a non-admin. I have multisite on a single node so on the data source I've put Sitecore query as **StartSearchLocation=query:./ancestor::*[@@templatename->'Site Folder']&Filter=_templatename:some_template_name**.

The above query returns the expected result for users with admin privilege, but not for the non-admin users. For non-admin users, its data keeps on loading and it does not return any result.

While verifying the ajax call found that there is a null exception on the call. Attached the screenshot below
[image]

I have verified the item permission for the Site Folder template and all its ancestors. Yet the issue exists for the non-admin users. I have reindexed the Master DB in Solr as well. Kindly let me know if any other suggestion or fix for this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This looks like a Sitecore bug. What version of Sitecore are you on? Have you submitted a Sitecore Support ticket for this issue yet?

Comment: Hi @DanSinclair. I'm using Sitecore 8.1 (rev. 160519) version. But I haven't created any support ticket to Sitecore.

Comment: I would start by creating a support ticket with Sitecore to see if they already have a fix for it they can provide.

Comment: @DanSinclair Thanks for the support. I have fixed the issue. Also, I've posted the solution to the issue.

Answer (score 1):

One of Sitecore member has analysed the exception and recommended to verify the User/Role access viewer. I have verified the access viewer and found that read permission is missing for **/sitecore/system/Settings/Buckets/Item Buckets Settings** and by providing the read permission for the **/sitecore/system/Settings/Buckets/Item Buckets Settings** item has resolved the issue.

Thanks for the support.